# XCode 7 Beta 5 and 6 simulator errors

Tags: ios, xcode

I have installed XCode 7 Beta 5 and 6 but I am not able to see the simulators to run my code anywhere. I have also downloaded iOS 8.4 simulator from XCode prefrences but still the same.

I am getting errors like Simulator cannot start etc.

Can you pls guide me as to what can be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you restart the computer?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that... it doesnt work...

Comment: Okay, do this: choose Window > Devices (in Xcode) and, one by one, select every simulator and delete it until there are none left. Now use the Plus button at the bottom to recreate any simulators you want. Now they will work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully resolve this by upgrading to the final stable release of Xcode.

Thanks everyone for responding.

Comment: Would you mind extending the answer bit more for fellow programmers to understand, how it helped solving the problem.